# Django Registration - using extended usercreation form. The login is activated before clicking the activation link

Tags: django-registration

I have a registraion form with the basic details and an extended user form with aditional field. The registration works fine, the mail is sent with actiavtion link. But before the activation link is clicked the login in active. I can login with the usernama and password i used for regsitraion even before the activation link is clicked.

Could someone please help and let me know where i am missing:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ExtentedUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            user.is_active = False

            profile.user = user

            profile.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)

            mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
            message = render_to_string('registration/acc_activate_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'profile': profile,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                #'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, 'spraysyndb-support@uni-due.de',to=['spraysyndb-support@uni-due.de']
            )
            email.send()
            return render(request, 'thankyou.html')
            #return HttpResponse('Welcome to the SpraysynDB, you would receive an confirmation from the admin. Thank you')


    else:
        form = ExtentedUserCreationForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'registration/regform.html', context )



def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        auth_login(request, user)
        return render(request, 'userlogindetails.html')
        #return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account at www.spraysyndb/login.de')

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Comment: i see that once i register the user is set to active inspite of setting the user.is_active = False. I really dont understand what i am missing. Please help

Comment: resolved - in the login part i missed setting the user.is_active = False